# Llamar a función de un contrato en la testnet

Tags: solidity, blockchain

La pregunta tiene un millón de respuestas en internet y ninguna parece querer funcionarme.

Por supuesto, algo estaré haciendo mal

Soy minter de un contrato en la Testnet y estoy tratando de crear un contrato que haga un par de cosas y por último, llame a la función de mint, tal que así:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.11;

contract DoobieMinter{
    function mint4Me(address _to, uint256 _value, address _contract) public{
        Doobie d = Doobie(_contract);
        d.mint(_to, _value);
    }
}

interface Doobie {
  function addMinters ( address[]  calldata _addedMinters ) external;
  function admin (  ) external view returns ( address );
  function allowance ( address _owner, address _spender ) external view returns ( uint256 _value );
  function approve ( address _spender, uint256 _value ) external returns ( bool );
  function balanceOf ( address ) external view returns ( uint256 );
  function changeAdmin ( address _newAdmin ) external;
  function decimals (  ) external view returns ( uint8 );
  function decreaseAllowance ( address _spender, uint256 _value ) external returns ( bool );
  function increaseAllowance ( address _spender, uint256 _value ) external returns ( bool );
  function isMinter ( address _addr ) external view returns ( bool );
  function mainchainGateway (  ) external view returns ( address );
  function mint ( address _to, uint256 _value ) external returns ( bool _success );
  function minter ( address ) external view returns ( bool );
  function minters ( uint256 ) external view returns ( address );
  function name (  ) external view returns ( string memory );
  function removeAdmin (  ) external;
  function removeMinters ( address[]  calldata _removedMinters ) external;
  function symbol (  ) external view returns ( string memory );
  function totalSupply (  ) external view returns ( uint256 );
  function transfer ( address _to, uint256 _value ) external returns ( bool _success );
  function transferFrom ( address _from, address _to, uint256 _value ) external returns ( bool _success );
}
```

La interfaz la cree a partir del ABI utilizando [esta herramienta](https://bia.is/tools/abi2solidity/)

Cuando lanzo el contrato en la testnet y ejecuto la función recibo el mensaje:

**"Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }"**

Por supuesto, de funcionar, solo lo haría si soy yo quien manda en el mensaje, ¡así que este sería otro problema llegado a ese punto!

Necesitaría especificar que la función es llamada desde la wallet que es minter, así sea agregando su private key al contrato y esto lo he intentando infructuosamente de mil maneras (De igual forma, no habría podido probarlo)

Estoy usando Remix IDE

¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: La funcionalidad de todo el contrato está dividido en varios contratos o esta todo en un solo contrato?

Comment: Si, existe el contrato de la moneda minteable y el contrato que debería llamar a mintear. He pensado en si debería volverlo a subir con estas funciones juntas y que sea un solo contrato, pero no resuelve el tema de que solo el  minter puede generar monedas y yo quiero que al recargar MATIC a través del otro contrato (o función si estuviesen juntos) se minteen y transfieran unas monedas a cambio

Comment: PS: El contrato es una copia de el SLP de Axie infinity. Acá se puede ver:

https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0xb25cf6697e4ecdd1960da585b4b2c7746ea2da03#code